# Error while constructing XML in ballerina

Tags: xml, ballerina

The following statement gives me compilation error in ballerina but when I remove the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

it works without any issues. Is there any thing I am missing here

```
xml req = xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns="urn:worldwire"
                   xmlns:cct="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.07"
                   xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
                   ${buildPacs008Header(bulkSend)}
                   ${buildPacs008Body(bulkSend)}
               </Message>`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML literal only allows to have a single XML element. This has been discussed in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/9275) as well You need to declare it separately and concatenate as below

```
xml x1 = xml`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;
xml req = x1 + xml `<Message xmlns="urn:worldwire"
                   xmlns:cct="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.07"
                   xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
               </Message>`;
```